# Shell: save ssh command result to local variable

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a ssh command that sends back a number:

```
ssh ${user}@${hostname} "wc -l < ${workspace}/logs"
```

where `${user},${hostname},${workspace}`are variables.

Now I want to save the result to a local variable called `lines`, I tried:

```
lines=${ssh ${user}@${hostname} "wc -l < ${workspace}/logs" }
```

But it does not work, why?

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of logs in workspace/logs, or the number of lines within the logs?

Comment: @GeneralBrae I want to count line number in the file called "logs"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command should be wrapped in "()" not "{}" when assigning fetching the result to a variable. Also, the others are just variables not commands so don't need a wrapper (assuming they are defined in a script or something).

```
lines=$(ssh $user@$hostname "wc -l < $workspace/logs")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$()` to get the result of command, not `${}` (in bash at least). The line below assumes that `workspace` is a variable defined on the host executing the `lines=`, not on the remote (if it was on the remote you would need to escape the `$`: `\${workspace}/logs`

```
lines=$(ssh ${user}@${hostname} "wc -l < ${workspace}/logs" )
```